# Mapping Custom Fields to Contact Roles

Tags: custom-field, opportunitycontactrole

I am trying to map a Custom Field in a Contact to the Contact Role section on an Opportunity and can't figure out how to map them out. Any advice? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

The OpportunityContactRole SObject has all sorts of limitations

- You can not add custom fields to it (as of V31)
- You can not write triggers against it (as of V31)

You can, however, add/remove Contact Roles

Your alternative would be to create a new custom junction object between Contact and Opportunity and manage as any other custom junction object - including adding custom fields